# How to bake Angular CLI based ng2/4 application into Node/Express and have single echo system to develop/run/debug Server/Client applications?

Tags: node.js, angular, express, angular-cli

I am trying to create Node/Express application with Angular 2/4 for front-end. For Angular I am using Angular CLI to create and maintain modules/components/services.

Angular CLI is creating an embryo application of ng2, and I can run/debug that application along during development. However server side application is different. Now I am having two different folder structure as below.

```
\repository
|   +-- server-app
|      +-- server.js
|      +-- package.json
|   +-- client-app
|      +-- main.ts
|      +-- index.html
|      +-- app
|         +-- AppComponent.ts
|      +-- package.json
```

I am using Visual Studio Code  as IDE. while development I end up in running the Node server for API's and then run Angular application with "ng serve". Trust me, development especially debugging is getting painful.

How to bake Angular CLI based application into Node/Express and have single echo system to develop/run/debug Server/Client applications?

Comment: it's not really clear what you are trying to ask here.  Angular CLI creates a node based app, but can be integrated into any web server in production.  It *sounds like* you are trying to say that you developed a server side app in node **separately** from the node app that is part of Angular CLI;  are you asking how to merge these into one app?

Comment: I am not worried about how to organize this in production, it is just placing the dist folder in server path. My question is more on developing and debugging in development environment. Updated the question with more details.